# Angular 5 HTTP load json file error

Tags: wordpress, api, http, angular5

**newsService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { INews } from './inews';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class NewsserviceService {
      public _url = 'http://localhost/admin/demo/api/get_posts/';
      constructor( public http: HttpClient) { }
      getNews(): Observable<INews[]> {
        return this.http.get<INews[]>(this._url).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
      }
     }
```

**newsComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsserviceService } from './newsservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-news-ticker',
  templateUrl: './news-ticker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news-ticker.component.scss']
})
export class NewsTickerComponent implements OnInit {
  public news: any[];
  constructor(private newsservice: NewsserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadNews();
  }
  loadNews(): void {
    this.newsservice.getNews().subscribe(res => this.news = res);

  }

}
```

**newscomponent.html**

```
<section class="news-ticker">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="ticker">
          <strong class="pull-left">news flash</strong>
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor='let news of news'>
              {{news.content}}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**console error**

ERROR TypeError: res.json is not a function
    at MapSubscriber.project (newsservice.service.ts:14)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:81)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:85)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:136)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:20)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)

Answer (score 0):

its better that you write some info about your problem however your problem refer to

```
 getNews(): Observable<INews[]> {
            return this.http.get<INews[]>(this._url).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
      }
```

in your service change it to :

```
   getNews():Observable {
        return this.http.get(this._url)
      }
```

since the method give us observable we should subscribe it in target component you can just do :

```
loadNews() {
    this.newsservice.getNews().subscribe(res => this.news = res);

  }
```

Comment: when i changed to above codes working fine with local json file, when i use json api from server shows  Failed to load http://localhost/kgpa-admin/kgpa/api/get_recent_posts/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.